# Rails and RSpec Variable Scope With Shortening Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having problems with shortening namespace as below in RSpec. I need to know how to do it safely in RSpec (after I explain) and in Rails controllers because I'm doing similarly in Rails controllers.

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::AreaService do
    Service=Api::V1::AreaService // I will be using Service instead of Api::V1::AreaService
    it 'should save a new area' do
        expect {
            Service.add 'some', 'area' // This is one example
        }.to change(Area, :count).by(1)
    end
end
```

If I run this independently, it passes. However it will fail if I run the whole test suite. When enabling debug just before Service.add(), I'm seeing Service = Some::Other::Service. This means it's not thread safe I get this. However, is there a way to shorten the services' name in RSpec?

Now my second question is will I have similar issues if I do this in controllers.

```
class MyModule::AreaController < MyModule::MainController
    Service = Api::V1::AreaService
    def add
        area = params['area']
        city = params['city']
        Service.add area, city
    end
end
```

Will I run into thread safe problems? If so, how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try moving your `Service = Api::V1::AreaService` assignment inside `before(:each)` block?

Comment: Why not just use `let(:service){ Api::V1::AreaService }`? You don't have to use a constant.

Comment: Oops. I think you guys are right. I'll try it later to confirm. However, I still have the second question as for rails controller. Do you guys know anything?

Comment: it worked but I have to use smaller case: let(:service). Thanks